# sing-box tun interface openwrt problem

Tags: linux, vpn, openwrt

I recently installed Sing-Box on my OpenWrt router for network management purposes.
However, I'm encountering an issue where Sing-Box is not permitted to create a TUN (network tunnel) interface. This problem is preventing me from setting up VPN connections and other network tunneling functionalities.

Could anyone provide insights or solutions on how to grant the necessary permissions to Sing-Box for creating a TUN interface on an OpenWrt system?
Any tips on configuring OpenWrt to allow this operation would be highly appreciated

```
   "inbounds": [
        {
            "auto_route": true,
            "strict_route": true,
            "domain_strategy": "",
            "endpoint_independent_nat": false,
            "inet4_address": "172.19.0.1/28",
            "interface_name": "nekoray-tun",
            "mtu": 1500,
            "sniff": true,
            "sniff_override_destination": false,
            "stack": "system",
            "tag": "tun-in",
            "type": "tun"
        }
    ],`
```

I did the input and output correctly and set it like this